# Experience Editor rendering context

Tags: experience-editor, commands

We are creating some custom buttons on the ribbon of a rendering in the experience editor that when clicked will trigger custom events listed in the commands.config.

The command executes just fine, the problem we are running into is that we do not have the renderings context that the button is on.  Is there a way to achieve this?  One thought has been to use some parameters passed in the button click via the button configuration in the core db but I am still not sure how we would tell it what rendering we are on.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the steps below to configure the custom button.

Create your custom button in the path `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Custom Experience Buttons` in core database.

For example, I created a custom button and copied the click event from change component position.

[image]

In the `master` database, navigate to your rendering.
There is a field `Experience Editor Buttons`, you will see a multilist containing the button you created.
Select the button you want for the rendering.

[image]

In Experience Editor, the button will appear when the rendering is configured.

[image]